# How do you Flatten List<T> in C# if T = List<T>?

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core

I have a c# method which passes a dictionary with generics, for example:

```
private void SaveData<T>(Dictionary<string, T> results) where T : class
{
   var listOfResults = results.Select(x => x.Value).ToList();     

   // If T is a list
   if (typeof(T).IsGenericType && typeof(T).GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
   {
      // HELP HERE, how do I collapse the list of lists?
   }
   else 
   {
      SaveToTheDatabase(listOfResults);
   }
}
```

We know that T could be a single value or it could be a list of values. The first if statement is supposed to check if T is a list. The else assumes it's a single value.

The spot where I have the comment, HELP HERE, how do I collapse the list of lists?

Comment: what does the signature for `SaveToTheDatabase` look like?

Comment: SaveToTheDatabase is a private variable with the type of Action<List<T>>

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, mine is flatten list in LINQ with generics. Different question

Comment: Wouldn't you want to check it T is a list before creating your `listOfResults`?

Comment: I don't see how... that question uses generics too, it just happens to be that `T` in that question is `int`.

Comment: @itsme86 I'm flattening the Dictionary<string, T> into the variable listOfResults.

Comment: So your `listOfResults` of type `List<T>` is actually `List<List<U>>`, and you don't know the `U`. The question by @DanielA.White makes sense because looks like you have to convert it to `List<U>` and pass it to a generic method (not action) with `U` generic argument.

Comment: @DavidG How `T` could be `List<T>`?

Comment: @DavidG, @IvanStoev is correct. T could be a List<K>. I tried playing around with this: `var tmp = listOfResults.Cast<List<object>>().SelectMany(x => x).ToList();` which didn't work because the complier didn't know how to cast that.

Comment: Yeah, of course! Better to just have two methods where one takes a `Dictionary<string, List<T>>` instead. Then you can get rid of the pesky reflection code.

Comment: DavidG is correct -- this works much better if you have *two* methods, one which saves a `Dictionary<string, T>` and one which saves a `Dictionary<string, List<T>>`  If you are doing a type test in a generic, that is a strong sign that you actually need to have two methods.  Alternatively, move the problem into SaveToTheDatabase, and make *it* flatten the sequence it receives.